# How can I prevent accumulating memory usage of a thread that reads from database in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, multithreading, memory

I have a code that uses a thread to periodically read data from a mysql database and make a dataframe of that data. On a shorter interval it uses a thread to periodically use that data (in this example a simple print). Every time new data is read, the old data becomes irrelevant. The problem is that this code accumulates memory usage every time the first thread (that gets the data) runs. How can that be prevented?

I have tried things with garbage collector, without success though.

```
## import libraries
from time import sleep
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd
import threading
import numpy as np
import gc

## define function to get data from mysql database and make pandas dataframe
def get_HLC():
    db=sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',database='algo')
    df=pd.read_sql('select *from ticks',con=db,parse_dates=True)
    df=pd.DataFrame(df)
    df=df.set_index(['timestamp'])
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.astype(np.int64), unit='ms')
    df2 = df.resample('60s', how={'last_price': 'ohlc'})
    df3 = df.resample('60s', how={'volume': 'sum'})
    df3.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('volume', 'sum')])
    df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)
    df4.iloc[:,3] = df4.iloc[:,3].fillna(method='ffill')
    df4.iloc[:,0] = df4.iloc[:,0].fillna(value=df4.iloc[:,3])
    df4.iloc[:,1] = df4.iloc[:,1].fillna(value=df4.iloc[:,3])
    df4.iloc[:,2] = df4.iloc[:,2].fillna(value=df4.iloc[:,3])
    df5 = df4.iloc[-230:,:]
    db.close()
    del(db, df, df2, df3, df4)
    gc.collect()
    return df5['last_price']['high'], df5['last_price']['low'], df5['last_price']['close']

## define function that gets the data in a loop
def thread1_Function():
    while True:
        global low
        df5 = get_HLC()
        low = df5[1]
        del(df5)
        gc.collect()
        sleep(30)

## start a thread of the get data loop
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1_Function)
thread1.start()

## pause 
sleep(5)

## define function that loops and does things with data of thread1
def thread2_Function():
    while True:
        #do things with thread1 data
        print(low)
        sleep(15)

## start a thread of the do things with data of thread1 loop
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2_Function)
thread2.start()
```

Comment: Start by closing your database connection. And this question might be more suitable over at codereview.stackexchange.com :) another quick fix would be to release any variables you don't need with `del(var)`.

Comment: Edited the code with db.close() and del(var), still have the memory issue.

Comment: I suggest you read up on articles regarding profiling, one good article is [this](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2013/06/08/python-profiling-tools/) one that shows an example of how to use kcachegrind and cprofiler to get a feel for debugging things like this. This should show you exactly where you're using up memory, my suspect is the `SELECT * FROM` that reads in the entire database into a variable that doesn't get dumped, but i've never used pandas - so maybe they take care of it for you some how.